# vcsode terminal horizontal breaks after upgrade

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode in MacOS Sierra.
After upgrading my vscode to 1.17.0，my terminal becomes like this:

[image]

Is there a way to fix it back to:

[image]

Comment: Does the terminal prompt look normal from the terminal app?

Comment: @ifconfig it looks normal in terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35649 which should be fixed by the 1.17 recovery build

In the future, please file bugs like this against the [VS Code repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new)